# Deploy long assignment rule from sandbox to production?

Tags: deployment, bestpractice, assignment-rules

**What is the easiest way** to deploy long (~100 steps) assignment rule from sandbox to production?

Edit: Currently it is not possible to automate this. What I am looking is for best practices to reduce the inevitable human error during manual deployment of ~100 steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000KktmAAC

http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Ih77

Unfortunately salesforce has no metadata API for this component and hence this will be manual process until salesforce comes up with metadata API to allow support for migration.

See the Metadata API documentation here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/meta_unsupported_types.htm?SearchType=Stem

Above list gets us all the components that are not supported through Metadata API deployment

Comment: Thank you, do you know any best practices? I raised this question because manually migrating so many steps will have human error. Any way to minimize this "human error"?

Comment: In eclipse we have Assignment Rule Object so wont be bad idea to observe the total count and i dont think we have anything that can be used to reduce inevitable errors.Best would be to have it peer reviewed from other team members